# How to split a string variable in variables in R (non-rectangular)

Tags: r, string, split, dataframe

I have the following variable in a dataframe

```
test<-data.frame(x=c("", "1-7-9", "3", "2-4-6-8"))
```

I want to splits that in variables like:

```
Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
NA   NA   NA   NA
1    7    9
3    NA   NA   NA
2    4    6   8
```

I have tried

```
 test2<-strsplit(as.character(vartest$x), "\\-")
```

but I get a list rather a dataframe

Please help me

Answer (score 5):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)[, tstrsplit(x, "-", type.convert = TRUE, fixed = TRUE)]
#    V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1: NA NA NA NA
# 2:  1  7  9 NA
# 3:  3 NA NA NA
# 4:  2  4  6  8
```

Note: [data.table dev version 1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation). The `type.convert` argument and factor to character conversion have been implemented in the latest dev version per [#1094](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1094) (Thanks Arun!).

Or

```
splitstackshape::cSplit(test, "x", "-")
#    x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4
# 1:  NA  NA  NA  NA
# 2:   1   7   9  NA
# 3:   3  NA  NA  NA
# 4:   2   4   6   8
```

These both return data tables that can be converted back to data frames by assigning the result then using `setDF()`.  They also both properly convert the numeric characters to classed "integer" columns.

---

And just for fun, a really difficult way to get a data frame back with `scan()`

```
x <- as.character(test$x)
v <- max(vapply(strsplit(x, "-", fixed = TRUE), length, 1L))
s <- scan(text = x, what = as.list(integer(v)), sep = "-", fill = TRUE, 
    na.strings = "", blank.lines.skip = FALSE)
setNames(data.frame(s), make.names(seq_along(s)))
#   X1 X2 X3 X4
# 1 NA NA NA NA
# 2  1  7  9 NA
# 3  3 NA NA NA
# 4  2  4  6  8
```

Comment: I have a funny feeling that are you going to keep adding solutions all night :)

Comment: Make a PR on `type.convert` for `tstrsplit` then :)

Comment: I think I might. I pinged Arun in the chat room

Answer (score 3):

Some other other options

```
library(tidyr) 
separate(test, x, paste0("Var", 1:4), extra = "merge", convert = TRUE)
#   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
# 1   NA   NA   NA   NA
# 2    1    7    9   NA
# 3    3   NA   NA   NA
# 4    2    4    6    8
```

And (using partially your solution - though types are not guarantied)

```
library(stringi)
data.frame(stri_list2matrix(strsplit(as.character(test$x), "-", fixed = TRUE), byrow = TRUE)) 
#    X1   X2   X3   X4
# 1 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 2    1    7    9 <NA>
# 3    3 <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 4    2    4    6    8
```

Or (contributed by @Richard) a complete `stringi` version of the above

```
data.frame(stri_split_fixed(test$x, "-", simplify = NA, omit_empty = NA))
#     X1   X2   X3   X4
# 1 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 2    1    7    9 <NA>
# 3    3 <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 4    2    4    6    8
```

Comment: Check out `stringi::stri_split_fixed(test$x, "-", simplify = NA)`

Comment: @RichardScriven that's a nice one

Comment: Also, `stringi` converts factors automatically so we don't need `as.character()`, which is really nice too

Comment: Yes, and it has `simplify` argument too. And `separate` has a `type.convert` argument aperantly...

Answer (score 2):

This is a base attempt, although it fails to populate the first row with NA's, and some testing shows that it never coverts the empty character item to a rows of NA's.

```
dat <- read.table(text=as.character(test$x), sep="-", 
                   fill =TRUE,col.names=paste0("Var", 1:4) )
> dat
  Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
1    1    7    9   NA
2    3   NA   NA   NA
3    2    4    6    8
```

Answer (score 0):

Using base R:

```
x <- strsplit(as.character(test$x),"-")
nc <- max(sapply(x, length))
out <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(x, "[", 1:nc)))
names(out) <- paste("var", 1:nc, sep = "")

> out
  var1 var2 var3 var4
1 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
2    1    7    9 <NA>
3    3 <NA> <NA> <NA>
4    2    4    6    8
```